# ASP.NET Core 3.0 change default endpoint route with attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

App is on ASP.NET Core, we recently migrated to 3.0.

I need to navigate to **mycontroller/login**, so login action instead of default index action but struggle with changing the default controller action method.
I keep getting my index page, only when I manually navigate to /login, I will get the page.
Also as a convention thing I need to keep the attribute routing.

```
[Route("/mycontroller")]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
       private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;

        public MyController(IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
        {

            _authenticationService = authenticationService;
        }

        [Route("login")]
        [HttpPost("login")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    var user = await _authenticationService.PerformCheckAndLogin(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        var userClaims = new List<Claim>
```

In my Configure method I tried:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=mycontroller}/{action=login}");
        });
```

Comment: Try to use `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });`

Comment: @picolino I tried it already, same thing.

Comment: Do you mean you want to navigate to `mycontroller/login` when going on `mycontroller`?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple redirecting at the top of my Index action method did the work, after checking if the user is logged in or not redirect to login page.

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            if (true)// implement cookie policy
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
```